# Image translation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not a very good programmer so if this is a stupid question forgive me !
I am just learning image transformation in ios
i want to translate a image from one position to another on button click event
Here is the code...

```
- (IBAction)showinfobybutton:(id)sender {
    CGFloat v1 = imageview.center.x;
    CGFloat v2 = imageview.center.y;
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(imageview.transform, v1, v2);
    imageview.transform = trans; 
}
```

What's wrong with the code. it only translate in y direction not in x. no matter how much you put the value for v1 function don't care. any idea what's going on .....
I am totally stucked
Thank You for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of your question about `CGAffineTransform`, a couple of thoughts:

1. Are you doing this in `init` method or `viewDidLoad`? If so, that may be too early in the view creation process as many of the `UIView` related properties of the `imageview` (such as `center`) are not reliable at that point. Take a look and make sure you're getting non-zero values for `v1` and `v2`. If you want to look at frame coordinates or the like, you might want to defer that until `viewDidAppear` or later.
2. Are you using autolayout? Open up the storyboard or NIB and look at the document properties (below). If you're moving things around on the screen, you might want to turn that off.

   [image]
3. As an aside, your setting `v1` and `v2` based upon the `center` of the `imageview` is curious. You're moving the `center` by the amount of the `center`. Usually you'd see something like the following:

   ```
   CGFloat dx = 100.0;
   CGFloat dy = 200.0;

   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                    animations:^{
                        CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.someView.transform, dx, dy);
                        imageview.transform = trans;
                    }];
   ```

   By the way, I animate (a) because that's often a better user experience; and (b) when doing diagnostics like this, it makes it easier for me to see what it's changing from and what it's changing to. If you don't want animation, obviously don't use `animateWithDuration` code.

---

By the way, if you want to move a `UIView` control, if you're not using autolayout, the most common way is to use `animationWithDuration` to change either the `center` or the `frame`, e.g.:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     imageview.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY); // set newX and newY to whatever you want
                 }];
```

If you're using autolayout, the process is a little more complicated. One technique in autolayout is to programmatically change the constraints, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Just now i found out in my code that if i put v1's value to a very high value ex 465465746574547 then it makes small random move in x direction